# ORACLE PL/SQL missing keyword error

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

The code

```
   SELECT some_identifier_id INTO a_someid_id FROM "SOME_IDENTIFIER" SOME_IDT
  INNER JOIN "CASE" cse ON cse.customer_id = '1001'
  INNER JOIN "MEASURE" m ON m.case_id = cse.case_id
WHERE SOME_IDT.some_identifier_type_code = '430101';
```

Gives out an "missing keyword" error. Where the problem lies?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `INTO` only when you execute the query in a PL/SQL program block (either anonymous, trigger, stored proc...).

An SQL query cannot contain an `INTO` clause, and it will give you this error.

```
-- Will fail
SELECT 1 INTO x FROM dual;

-- Will succeed
declare x int;
begin
   SELECT 1 INTO x FROM dual;
end;
```

Comment: Goofy question. You could post this answer to comments, so I could close it :) Anyway, thanks for help.

Comment: I don't understand. Why wouldn't I post my answer as an answer? Anyway, glad I could help.

Comment: Never mind, that's my afterthoughts to posting this question here. Could have guessed, that there are no variables in query.